# Difference between Where and Join on Id

Tags: sql, join, syntax, left-join, where-clause

I recently saw this query, which finds all the party a client can go to:

```
SELECT *
FROM Party
    INNER JOIN Organizer on Organizer.OrganizerId = Party.OrganizerId
    LEFT JOIN Client on Client.ClientID = 1
    LEFT JOIN PartyRegistration on PartyRegistration.PartyId = Party.PartyId
WHERE Party.OrganizerId = 0
    AND (Party.HasGuestList = 0 OR PartyRegistration.ClientId = Client.ClientId)
```

I had never seen a join on a specific value before. Is it normal to see SQL code like this?

I don't have much knowledge of left joins but it can apply to any join, for example, how would this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Party
    INNER JOIN Organizer on Organizer.OrganizerId = 0
```

compare to that since the results are the same:

```
SELECT *
FROM Party
    INNER JOIN Organizer on Organizer.OrganizerId = Party.OrganizerId
WHERE Organizer.OrganizerId = 0
```

Comment: This can only be a matter of good/bad practice if you compare to an alternative. Putting a test in a left join on vs a where does two different things--so it's not a matter of good/bad practice. This may be an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/266284). If you want to understand in terms of alternatives give a [mcve]. But if so first google faqs re putting a test in a left join on vs a where.

Comment: No, if I had complete knowledge of SQL I would easily be able to give you and example. So easy in fact that I would not have to ask this question. I did not write this code, the dev before me did, what I want to know if this is a normal, good practice to achieve what is being achieve.

Comment: What is the point of your comment? PS Again--"normal" *for what*--to acheive *what*?

Comment: To answer yours? because my question is not a XY? To explain why I can't give an alternative, to explain why I ask the question in the first place.

Comment: Would someone who works with SQL write something like this? Or "conforming to a standard; usual, typical, or expected." as Oxford defines normal.

Comment: You have jumped to a conclusion or are not asking the question you want to by phrasing in terms of "bad"--there cannot be bad practice unless there is an alternative. Think about the question you actually want to ask.

Comment: @philipxy I updated the question.

Comment: Your added code switches from left join to inner join. It does something different. It asks a different question. If you don't understand how joins work please research that then if you are stuck ask a question about understanding some authorative presentation. PS For inner join on vs where you *can* put a condition in either. A faq. For left join you can't. A faq. An inner join on or where that requires a right table column to be not null after a left join on removes any rows extended by nulls, ie leaves only inner join on rows, ie "turns outer join into inner join". A faq.

Comment: Please ask one question per post. But they're all faqs--whether you can & when you should use on vs where for inner & outer joins. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: @philipxy Is this a duplicate? if so flag it. It was the same question in my mind, since as mentionned before I didn't realize the difference between the two join types. I did not have any error message, I did search before posting. You shoudl consider looking at [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) because your answer was not clear either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very good practice -- in fact, you cannot (easily) get this logic in a `WHERE` clause.

A `LEFT JOIN` returns all rows in the first table -- even when there are no matches in the second.

So, this returns all rows in the preceding tables -- and any rows from `Client` where `ClientId = 1`.  If there is no match on that `ClientId`, then the columns will be `NULL`, but the rows are not filtered.

Comment: Does that mean it is also good practice to remove the `WHERE Party.OrganizerId = 0` to instead put the id within the `INNER JOIN` `on` condition?

Comment: @Halhex It is not a matter of good practice, it is a matter of right or wrong result. With an inner join after all left joins, you have a choice to put a test in on or where, so bad/good practice becomes relevant. Read the first line of this answer. (And see my answer.)

Comment: @Halhex . . . That is a matter of style.  I think most people would put the filtering conditions in the `where` clause.  The filtering in the `on` clause is different -- if you move the condition to the `where` it changes the results.

Answer (score 1):

This can only be a matter of good/bad practice if you compare to an alternative. Putting a test in a left join on vs a where does two different things--so it's not a matter of good/bad practice.

If that is the *correct* left join condition, meaning you want inner join rows on that condition plus unmatched left table rows, then that is the left join condition. It wouldn't go anywhere else.

Learn what left join on returns: inner join on rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. Always know what inner join you want as part of a left join.

Comment: What does that even mean?? Compared to having the id in a where condition, as the question suggests.

Comment: "bad practice" compared to what? "having the id in a where condition" *does something different*, so if it were correct to be in the on it would be *wrong* to have it in the where so the where would not even be an option. *Why* is it in the on--so that we can compare to actual options--alternatives that do whatever it is that you want to do.

Comment: How is this an answer to my question? Is this "Learn what left join on returns: inner join on rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls." trying to explain left joins? What does "Always know what inner join you want as part of a left join." mean? Why are you so insistent while making so little sense?

Comment: Your original question invoves left join. You don't understand how it works, or you wouldn't have asked your question. So I am telling you to find out, and giving a quick but correct definition. It is clear from the definition given, because it is in terms of inner join, that you need to know the inner join associated with an outer join; I'm just stressing it. Your added code is about *inner* join on vs where. It asks a different question  than the first part of your answer. You are spending a lot of unhelpful time complaining instead of trying to understand what I am trying to communicate.

Comment: Prior knowledge of what I misunderstood is required to understand what your answer is saying. It is unhelpful. Though I can now see the confusion because I did think moving the `on` condition in a where was the same no matter the join type, I don't think this answer is actually useful to the question. Mostly looking at the answers by Gordon which are actual answers. My "complaints" were me trying to understand, why answer at all if it's to say I should go look somewhere else?

Answer (score -1):

That is true. Left join on a specific value is really bad practice. But some times, we may need to all the column from one table though we don't have common columns to join and required to join by specific condition like A="some value". In this case adding LEFT JOIN on specific condition bad practice, though we can little better way, below is updated code, Please let me know if you have any questions, I would be happy to help you on this.

```
SELECT *
FROM Party
    INNER JOIN Organizer on Organizer.OrganizerId = Party.OrganizerId
    LEFT JOIN Client USING(CLIENTID)
    LEFT JOIN PartyRegistration on PartyRegistration.PartyId = Party.PartyId
WHERE CLIENTID=1 AND Party.OrganizerId = 0
    AND (Party.HasGuestList = 0 OR PartyRegistration.ClientId = Client.ClientId)
```

Comment: Trying to use `USING` I get this error message *ClientId is not a recognized table hints option. If it is intended as a parameter to a table-valued function or to the CHANGETABLE function, ensure that your database compatibility mode is set to 90*.

Comment: my bad, i missed adding table alias. try like this, Client.ClientID

Comment: I also have the error *An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected* within the `USING`.

Comment: If that is the left join condition, meaning they want inner join rows on that condition plus unmatched left table rows, then that is the left join condition.